# iOS Swift unsupported URL

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I have a REST web service running on tomcat at 92.126.230.210:9090/delete(this is a fake ip but the structure is the same) that I want to consume but the compiler output tells to me "unsupported URL".

I have no spaces and all characters are in the ASCII table.

WS call:

```
//uriParam = 92.126.230.210:9090/delete?uid=SAFAKEWDW
func deleteUserRESTCall(uri uriParam: String){
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: uriParam)!) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: You need `https://` at the beginning

Comment: exactly you need https, http will be possible rejected in app approval... furthermore this code will be rejected because you don't support ipv6 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is missing a protocol, e.g. `https://92.126.230.210:9090/delete?uid=SAFAKEWDW`.